# jQuery-ui not styling Panel in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Problem trying to theme `Panel` content with jquery-ui
The `Panel` displays and shows the buttons defined, but they are not styled using `smoothness` theme?

Data.js

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

exports.get = function(content) {

    return data.url(content);
}
```

main.js

```
var confirmPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 450,
    height: 350,
    contentURL: Data.get("html/confirmPanel.html"),
    contentStyleFile: Data.get("lib/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"),
    contentScriptFile: [
                        Data.get("lib/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"),
                        Data.get("lib/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"),
                        Data.get("js/confirmPanel.js")
                        ]
});
```

confirmPanel.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Save</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Addon structure (in case its useful)

```
├── data
│   ├── html
│   │   └── confirmPanel.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── confirmPanel.js
│   │   └── SelectedText.js
│   └── lib
│       ├── css
│       │   └── smoothness
│       │       ├── images
│       │       │   ├── animated-overlay.gif
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
│       │       │   ├── ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
│       │       │   └── ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
│       │       └── jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css
│       └── js
│           ├── jquery-1.9.1.js
│           └── jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Panel` doesn't support `contentStyle*`
You can simply add the style directly in the HTML's document.